# Google Maps API with optimized waypoints. Waypoint_Order off

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having problems with the waypoint_order on some request it matches what the legs end location and other times it does not. Here is how I am sending the request along with the waypoints and legs.

```
    var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
        };
```

Waypoints being passed.

waypt[0] 1450 West Jackson Street Ozark Missouri ----order[0] 3

waypt[1] 2825 S Glenstone Ave Springfield Missouri ----order[1] 1

waypt[2] 404 West South Street Nixa Missouri ----order[2] 0

waypt[3] 500 West Chestnut Expressway Springfield Missouri ----order[3] 4

waypt[4] 715 W. Mt. Vernon Nixa Missouri ----order[4] 2

waypoint order: 3,1,0,4,2

Legs.

legs[0] from 1923 E Kearney St, Springfield, MO 65803, USA

legs[0] to 500 W Chestnut Expy, Springfield, MO 65806, USA

legs[1] from 500 W Chestnut Expy, Springfield, MO 65806, USA

legs[1] to 2825 S Glenstone Ave, Springfield, MO 65804, USA

legs[2] from 2825 S Glenstone Ave, Springfield, MO 65804, USA

legs[2] to 1450 W Jackson St, Ozark, MO 65721, USA

legs[3] from 1450 W Jackson St, Ozark, MO 65721, USA

legs[3] to 715 W Mt Vernon St, Nixa, MO 65714, USA

legs[4] from 715 W Mt Vernon St, Nixa, MO 65714, USA

legs[4] to 404 W South St, Nixa, MO 65714, USA

legs[5] from 404 W South St, Nixa, MO 65714, USA

legs[5] to 3315 S Campbell Ave, Springfield, MO 65807, USA

waypoint order according to legs: [2,1,4,0,3]

Does anybody know why the waypoint_order in result.routes[0].waypoint_order would be off?

Comment: Looks correct to me.